# iphone: How can add my application icon on the "Share Via" list?

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have created an application in iPhone. Now i want to add my app icon on the "share via" list
(The list that ask for share via: Facebook, twitter,whats app and other thing.. ).

So is there is any way to accomplish this task.

Any help will be appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve something like that in iOS is described here:

[My app inside iMessage UIActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991990/my-app-inside-imessage-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Comment: The answer you told to me was only work if we are inside our application. But if suppose i take a photo from the device and want to share it with the my application so how can i add my application icon in the "Share via" list.. 
Please tell to me if i went wrong..

Comment: Did you have a look at the referenced stack overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application? If that is not working it's not possible, Apple is quite restrictive in inter-app relations ...