# How can I share an Image to my Cordova/PhoneGap App from another App?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have a Cordova/PhoneGap App which deals with photos. What I want is to make my app appears in the sharing options, when other apps want to share a photo to other apps.

Here is an example for such a sharing dialog:

[image]

**How can I make that my Cordova/PhoneGap App appears in a Photo Sharing Options of other Apps?**

**Edit:** When I click on share to Instagram in some photo apps I get the following popup. How can I make that my app does appear in this share popup too?

[image]

Comment: look into this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991990/my-app-inside-imessage-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: @jcesarmobile How is this done with Android?

Comment: for android http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: @jcesarmobile When I click on share to Instagram in some photo apps I get the following popup. How can I make that my app does appear in this share popup too? (See the image in my edit)

Comment: Isn't that the same you asked on first place? I think the link on my firt comment should help you

Comment: Okay great thank you! If you give a full answer I can accept it.

Comment: done! I've added another link with more info for iOS

Comment: @confile: have u done it. i am looking for the same solution for ios8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS it's been answered on this thread

[My app inside iMessage UIActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991990/my-app-inside-imessage-uiactivityviewcontroller)

on this one you have even more info

[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

For android you can follow the instructions here
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html