# CFBundleDocumentType is not working in myproject-Info.plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an app in ionic framework.

I am trying to build this functionality like when i click on photo from gallery and hit share A share pan will open .  i want to show my app here.

I made some modification in plist file

here is code of my plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.jpeg</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
          <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>icon-40</string>
          <string>icon-small</string>
          <string>icon-60</string>
          <string>icon.png</string>
          <string>icon@2x</string>
          <string>icon-72</string>
          <string>icon-72@2x</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>icon-small</string>
          <string>icon-40</string>
          <string>icon-50</string>
          <string>icon-76</string>
          <string>icon-60</string>
          <string>icon</string>
          <string>icon@2x</string>
          <string>icon-72</string>
          <string>icon-72@2x</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.ionicframework.hitutest948556</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Part which i had added

```
 <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.jpeg</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
          <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
```

any suggestion for the same . As Still i am not able to see myapp into share pane

Thanks

Comment: And what's the issue?

Comment: i am not able to see myapp into sharepane/

Comment: can you put only the part you added and not the whole plist?

Comment: Are you using latest Xcode?

Comment: @NileshPatel: yes i am using latest one..

Comment: You missed to set UIFileSharingEnabled to YES, Because of that its not working. I think so.

Comment: Not working at my end

Comment: This seems to a photos issue. I can get my app in something like Dropbox coming up in the "Open In" list, but in photos is a no go. Can someone confirm that Apple does not allow this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several things are missing/wrong :

- CFBundTypeIconFiles : I'm quite suire you need to specify the icons for your app to appear
- CFBundleTypeName : You put the name of your application here
- CFBundleTypeRole : I think you want "Viewer" here
- LSHandlerRank : I think you want "Alternate" here (not sure you can be something else for a contentype like "public.jpeg")

This is an example **that works** to register your application. It's tested and works for *all types of data*. Work your way down from there to target only public.jpeg :

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon-22x29.png</string>
            <string>Icon-44x58.png</string>
            <string>Icon-64x64.png</string>
            <string>Icon-320x320.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My App</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have applied above code into myprohject-info.plist file. but nothing works.

Comment: I am not able to see my app on share menu.. I am using Phonegap Application

Comment: Then you have to check your app settings, because this works. This has to go in a file called "info.plist" when compiled for iOS. Open your compiled phone gap app for iOS on your PC (it's probably just a compressed file) and open the info.plist to see what's been generated, and check that these lines are there. If not, see how to make them go there with phone gap. If they are there, then you have a non working info.plist. Then restart from scratch for info.plist and add this at the right place (be cautious, the "dict" in the plist are prone to errors IMHO)

Comment: Put it at the end of info.plist also (same level as CFBundleIcons). Don't know if it changes something but just try.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `UIFileSharingEnabled` to `YES`. You missed to set it in plist.

Hope this will resolve your issue.