# ios cordova, cannot add app in share menu

Tags: ios, cordova, info.plist

I tried to follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725432/cfbundledocumenttype-is-not-working-in-myproject-info-plist-file#), but without success.

My application icon does not appear in the share menu of ios.

Can you confirm me that the app icon appears right after the app install ?
Is there a way to log or test this behaviour ?

Here is the config.xml part I use to generate the Info.plist (which is OK, verified by unzipping the ipa and checking the file) :

```
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIFileSharingEnabled">
        <true />
    </config-file>

    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleDocumentTypes">
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
                <array>
                    <string>icon-small</string>
                </array>
                <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                <string>AppName</string>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Viewer</string>
                <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                <string>Alternate</string>
                <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>public.image</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </config-file>
```

Best regards, Olivier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is that the app won't appear in photos share list only.

Photos app seems in cause and not the Info.plist declaration.

I will document this answer if I find a workaround of thi problem.

Regards, Olivier