# The value of the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in the Info.plist must be an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, info.plist

We are getting the below issue while uploading our app to app store although we are are not using CFBundleDocumentTypes in the app and the previous version uploaded successfully last week

ERROR ITMS-90149: "This bundle is invalid. The value of the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in the Info.plist must be an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing at least the CFBundleTypeName key.”

[image]

[image]

How can we solve this?

XCODE 11.3.1

thanks.

Comment: Already did this step .. but same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After So many hours of research finally made a successful upload to app store.

It seems apple have some changes in the submission of app.

we have the below in the `info.plist` which was working normally for the past 10 submission

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <string>public.url</string>
    <string>public.plain-text</string>
    <string>public.image</string>
</array>
```

After removing it and uploading to store everything worked normally
Dont know what is that related to `CFBundleDocumentTypes` but that was the reason

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed the same issue for me!

Answer (score 4):

hi can you open your info.plist file as a source and check if your CFBundleDocumentTypes key has the correct format ie

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
 <array>
    <dict>
    </dict>
 </array>
```

I guess in your case you are also missing CFBundleTypeName key which is a must
ie

```
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>Your App</string>
```

to get a complete idea of code refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725432/cfbundledocumenttype-is-not-working-in-myproject-info-plist-file)

Comment: thank you .. but the key doesnt exist at all in info.plist i opened it with text editor and search for it

Comment: Could it be something in entitlment.plist? we enabled Associated domains for the future under development version. I tried to add it to this version and also the same issue.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Thanks! For my case, on Xcode 14, I had to go edit the Info.Plist in the targets and just added a name to the "Document Types" Name section

Answer (score 1):

Solution: (You are missing some keys & values)

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a series of doc types but an empty  at the end I continue to miss (funny how you don't see these sort of things). It had been there for at least 2 prior distributions.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>GPS Exchange Format (GPX)</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.topografix.gpx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>JSON</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.json</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>   < ---- that one !
    </dict>
</array>
```